# Multiple variables in list and checking if list contains variable. Prolog

Tags: list, variables, prolog

i want to add member like that:

```
member(name(fred),age(33),sports([tenis,football])).
member(name(ann),age(18),sports([basketball,football])).
member(name(abc),age(26),sports([golf,tenis])).
member(name(cbd),age(40),sports([tenis])).


insert_member :- write('Name:'),read(Name),write('Age:'),read(Age),
                 write('sports:'),read([Sport1,Sport2]),
                 assert(member(name(Name),age(Age),sports([Sport1,Sport2]))).
```

but getting an error: ERROR: No permission to modify static procedure `member/3'
ᄀERROR: In:
ERROR:   [11] assert(member(name(rob),age(33),sports(...)))
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.

and second problem is if i want to check if a member age is >20 and got 'tenis' in sport and i do that like that:

```
check(N) :- member(name(N),age(K),sports(D),_),(K>20-> write(K),(D='tenis' -> write(D))).
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Check your spelling - did you really write "wrtite"?

Comment: please add a few member-facts ti make it easier to reproduce and discuss.

Comment: ye my bad i fix spelling

member(name(ann),age(18),sports([basketball,football])).
member(name(abc),age(26),sports([golf,tenis])).
member(name(cbd),age(40),sports([tenis])).

but it doesnt change nothing

Comment: do you still get the error mesage now? if not, please edit your question.

Comment: yes all the time same i just copied wrong i had it "write" sorry for that but problem is still same

Answer (score 0):

First question: In the third `read` you expect `sport1` and `sport2`, which are atoms and no variables. Using upper-case letters fixes it.

Second question: The format of member is wrong, it is a 3-arity predicate. The additional `_` belongs to sport as a second parameter. Also, if you want to check of tenis is part of the sport list, you may want to check all the entries. I demonstrated that with the predefined predicate `member/2`. I also changed the order of write assuming you only wanted to write the result if both conditions are true.

Code:

```
insert_member :- write('Name:'),read(Name),write('Age:'),read(Age),
                 write('sports:'),read([Sport1,Sport2]), 
                 assert(member(name(Name),age(Age),sports([Sport1,Sport2]))).

check(N) :- member(name(N),age(K),sports(L)),
            (K>20-> (member('tenis',L) -> write(K), write(" "), write('tenis'))).
```

Comment: 1st. i changed for upper-case letters but it still same problem

2nd. now i get error like that: ERROR: Unknown procedure: member/2
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [11] member(tenis, [tenis])

Comment: what do you enter in to the `read`s after you enter `insert_member.` ?

Comment: Name:rob.
Age:|: 33.
sports:|: tenis.
|: football.

Comment: @Mateusz. Sorry I was assuming you used SWI Prolog. What do you use?

Comment: I think you need to enter the list of sports [tenis, football].

Comment: insert_member.
Name:rob.
Age:|: 33.
sports:|: [a,b].
ERROR: No permission to modify static procedure `person/4'
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.

Comment: how does your member/3 -definition look?

Comment: ok, I don't see any person. Maybe you want to update the question with all relevant code and I'll update the answer.

Comment: guess you assumed - like me - that member/3 was a predicate for basic facts. I have asked for some examples 45 mins ago.

Comment: ok i updated everything i have in pr.pl  and added errors

Comment: your update cannot be your program. Where do you use the person/4-predicate?

Comment: i had throphies after sports but deleted it and now all errors and everything looks like that in my program

Comment: check is working perfect thanks
only have problem with this insert

Comment: what happens when you enter `[tenis,hockey].` in the third read?

Comment: ?- insert_member.
Name:r.
Age:|: 33.
sports:|: [tenis,hockey].

ERROR: No permission to modify static procedure `member/3'
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [11] assert(member(name(r),age(33),sports(...)))
ERROR:    [9] <user>
ERROR: 
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.

Comment: does it work when you replace `assert`with `dynamic`? According to the doc of [assert/1](https://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/DynamicCode.html) this is preferred.

Comment: no again error
ERROR: Type error: `predicate_indicator' expected, found `member(name(rob),age(33),sports([a,b]))' (a compound)
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [18] throw(error(type_error(predicate_indicator,...),_4674))
ERROR:   [14] '$set_pi_attr'(user:member(...,...,...),dynamic,true)
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.

Comment: Please post the SWI-Prolog version you are using and a screen shot of everything you enter before the error.

Comment: ver.8.2.4 dont know why its not working ;/
but got next problem dont know how to update values
member(name(cbd),age(40),sports([tenis])).
and update age to 45